# Minus result from a query from another query

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have 2 queries in Postgres and I would like to minus the result of the second query from the result of the first query.

First Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
nth_value(wos.endtime,1) OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wos.endtime ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as "Nth Onhold Start time" from wo_status_info wos
LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
WHERE wos.statusid = 1 AND wos.nextstatusid = 2
ORDER BY woas.workorderid
```

First Query Result

```
 |-------------------|-------------------------|
 |    workorderid    |  Nth Onhold Start time  |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|                 
 |         2         |       1515231826648     |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|                 
 |         6         |       1516456159371     |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|
```

Second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
nth_value(wos.endtime,1) OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY wos.endtime ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as "Nth Onhold Start time" from wo_status_info wos
LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
WHERE wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid = 1 OR wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid = 3
ORDER BY woas.workorderid
```

Second query result

```
 |-------------------|-------------------------|
 |    workorderid    |  Nth Onhold End time    |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|                 
 |         2         |       1515241744772     |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|                 
 |         6         |       1516456311878     |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|
```

I think I need to have these queries as sub query and some sort of self JOIN, but I am not sure on how to write this.

The JOIN should be on the workorderid

Required result

```
 |-------------------|-------------------------|
 |    workorderid    |        Difference       |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|                 
 |         2         |         9918124         |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|                 
 |         6         |         152507          |
 |-------------------|-------------------------|
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "except" instead of "minus"?
https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/except.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join two derived tables (i.e. queries like you have), one way to do it is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ...
) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ...
) b ON a.PK_column = b.PK_column
```

In your case:

```
SELECT a.workorderid, b.endtwo - a.endone AS difference
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
    nth_value(wos.endtime,1) OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY 
    wos.endtime ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as endone from wo_status_info wos
  LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
  WHERE wos.statusid = 1 AND wos.nextstatusid = 2
) a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT woas.workorderid, 
    nth_value(wos.endtime,1) OVER(PARTITION BY woas.workorderid ORDER BY 
    wos.endtime ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as endtwo from wo_status_info wos
  LEFT JOIN wo_assessment woas ON woas.assessmentid = wos.assessmentid
  WHERE wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid = 1 OR wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid = 3
) b ON a.workorderid = b.workorderid
ORDER BY a.workorderid
```

If you want to only return results if there are matching rows in both queries, change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  I also moved the `ORDER BY` to the outer query.  Is this what you are looking for?

Also, be careful with your `WHERE` clause and the `AND/OR` conditions.  When you have an `OR` mixed with `AND`s, you should always use parentheses to group conditions together.  Otherwise, your `OR` may unexpectedly override your other `AND` conditions:

```
WHERE wos.statusid = 2 
AND wos.nextstatusid = 1 
OR wos.statusid = 2 
AND wos.nextstatusid = 3
```

I think you want something like this:

```
WHERE 
  (wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid = 1) OR  
  (wos.statusid = 2 AND wos.nextstatusid = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, that basically it. I had a problem with the alias names so removed the blank spaces and it now works. I have edited your answer to reflect that.

Comment: Great, glad it worked :)  I accidentally rejected your edit.  Can you resubmit it, and I will approve it?  Sorry about that.